# Block syntax translation problems Objective C to Swift

Tags: ios, swift, translation, codeblocks, uipickerviewcontroller

```
TWPhotoPickerController *photoPicker = [[TWPhotoPickerController alloc] init];
photoPicker.cropBlock = ^(UIImage *image) {
    //do something
};
[self presentViewController:photoPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Been stuck on this for way too long. I have imported all the correct header files into my bridging header file... just need to know how do I translate this block into swift syntax?

Comment: Then why don't you read the relevant section in the Swift manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
var photoPicker = TWPhotoPickerController()
photoPicker.cropBlock = { (image: UIImage) -> () in
// do something
}    
presentViewController(photoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```